# SyntaxError when using validation for tkinter.Entry executed using exec()

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, exec, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a program containing various drop down menus and writable fields. To simplify adding new menus and writable fields i wanted to loop over a list of tuples containing the information required to create dynamic variable names and the menus.

The problem i am running into is when running the below code where 'name' is the string "Percentage". It should be noted that the code works if i remove 'validate' and 'validatecommand', though obviously the validation isn't done.

```
def number_validate(char):
    return char.isdigit()
self.percentage_validification = self.root.register(number_validate)

exec("self." + name + "_box" + " = " + "tkinter.Entry(self.root, validate = 'key', self.validatecommand = (self.validation, '%S'))")
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

The following code gives the correct output but does not allow dynamic variable naming and creation, which indicates that it is not a problem with the command itself:

```
self.Percentage_box = tkinter.Entry(self.root, validate = "key", validatecommand = (self.percentage_validification, '%S'))
```

I assume my problem relates to improper handling of strings in the exec function, but i simply can't figure out how is should be done. Does anyone have an answer.

Comment: Don't use exec. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue, but still converted it to dictionaries as you suggested since it seems much easier to use.